# Function receive parameters from two different sources

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there is any way that a function can receive two different parameters from two different sources. One source being an event target and the second being a variable produced in a different function.

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", combine);

function one(numbers){
  //numbers = [1,2,3]
  var test = numbers.push("4")
  combine(test)  
}

function combine (e,test){
  console.log (e.target)
  console.log(test)
}
```

When I try to console log both "e" and "test", usually one or the other returns undefined.

Is there any other way to add an array produced from one function and a event from an event listener?

Comment: `test` will just be `4`, not `[1,2,3,'4']`, by the way.

Comment: The important question is, how is `one()` being called?

Comment: You have two arguments in `combine` but you only ever pass one argument when you call it (or when the browser calls it), so the second one will always be undefined!

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way for a function to have an event "e" and a variable as a second parameter?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, function one is called on window load. function combine is called when there is a click on the window which works fine but only when "e" is the only parameter. I don't know how to get the "test" variable.

Comment: Let me just answer the question as stated: "I'm wondering if there is any way that a function can receive two different parameters from two different sources." — Some piece of code _calls_ the function and passes the parameters, so _No_, the function can't receive parameters from two different sources, only from the caller. The function can _obtain data_ if other _different_ ways, but those aren't parameters. Note that the caller can pass a function as a parameter to a function, and the function you called can get data by calling the function that was passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is call `combine` where the combine function retrieves the value from `one` ?

In which case it would be like:

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", combine);

function one(numbers){
  //numbers = [1,2,3]
  var test = numbers.push("4")
  return test;
}

function combine (e){
  let test = one(); //create locally scoped variable 'test' and get value from 'one' function
  console.log (e.target)
  console.log(test)
}
```

Otherwise you'd need to store the value in a variable that is accessible to both functions? The below assumes that 'numbers' parameter is initialized elsewhere?

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", combine);

var _test = [];
function one(numbers){
  //numbers = [1,2,3]
  //var test = numbers.push("4")
  //return test;

  numbers.push("4"); //assuming numbers is an array?
  _test = numbers;
}

function combine (e){
  console.log (e.target)
  console.log(_test)  // '_test' in this case is a variable available in overarching scope?
}
```

see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f4vbpsoe/1/

Answer (score 0):

supposing that you have called function "one" somewhere.

```
var test=numbers.push(4);
```

the value of "test" here will be "4" not "1 2 3 4"

when calling the "combine" function you have to put the 2 parameters otherwise the empty parameter will return undefined

the code should look something like that:

```
function one(){
  numbers = [1,2,3]
  numebrs.push(4);
  var test = numbers;
  combine(whatever,test)  
}

function combine (e,test){
  console.log (e.target)
  console.log(test)
}
```

Comment: i couldn't get this solution to work. The "whatever" parameter always showed up as undefined.  I even tried putting "" on the first variable inserting the ```test``` variable twice with no luck.

Comment: What is it you want to put in the place of the "whatever" parameter so i can help you better?